# Error compiling to teensy 3.6

Tags: arduino-ide, teensy

**Problem:**

In short, the Arduino IDE won't compile a sketch for the Teensy 3.6. It gives the error:

```
exec: "A:\\arduino-1.8.5\\hardware\\teensy/../tools/teensy_post_compile": file does not exist
Error compiling for board Teensy 3.6.
```

**What I have tried**

-Re-installing teensyduino (And yes, I have it installed, along with a compatible Arduino IDE (version 1.8.5))

-completely wiping the IDE and re-installing

-using a different USB cable

**Other information**

The OS I'm using is Windows 10

A broken Teensy is not out of the question, as I have been doing some soldering on it and I may have slipped or something, although I don't think that's the problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you running the IDE from a floppy disk? .... `A:` is the disk name for the floppy disk

Comment: It's my USB stick, I assigned it the letter `A:` so that it's easy to remember

Comment: Also so other programs that reference it (e.g. my python programs) don't have to be changed on the whim of windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix, it's not elegant or easy to use, but it works.

**Steps to take**

-Install a fresh version of teensyduino

-Make a copy of `[arduino directory]/hardware/tools` and save it anywhere as a backup (sometimes weird, buggy things happen)

-Make a copy of `teensy.exe` from the `tools` folder, and put it in the same directory as `arduino.exe`

-every time you run `arduino.exe` (don't double-click on a `.ino` file), first start `teensy.exe` and everything *should* work.

Sometimes, the `tools` directory gets deleted (It just seems a bit buggy), if that happens copy the backup and paste it where it should be (`[arduino directory]/hardware/tools`)

Also occasionally `teensy.exe` gets deleted, so make sure to have a backup of that as well.